# Why all versions of Android until now contains almost no GNU softwares?

Tags: linux, android, gnu

A GNU/Linux OS contain almost all GNU software (`nano`, `tar`, `bash`, `make`, etc.).

But how does Android? It even does not have a terminal by default for mobile. Google has replaced most of them by non-free softwares developed by Google.

Why Google did that?

Comment: [Android is not a GNU/Linux OS](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/android-and-users-freedom.html).

Comment: Just a comment: usually, `make` is not shipped with the distro.

Comment: `Why Google did that?` ... why do you believe that you can find out the true reason by asking here? ... you can only get `the reason could be...`, not `the reason is ...`

Comment: Because corporations love the unpaid labour aspect of open source, but don't like the "once free, always free" and "must share the source" requirements of copyleft licensing.  It's why they constantly undermine the GPL and push BSD-like licenses which don't have such obligations via propaganda and non-GPL replacements.  Linux-based Android was Google's way in to the smart phone market, and Free Software and open-ness was a compelling advantage at the time...but now they have market dominance, they don't need that any more, in fact those things are now a hindrance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is Android based upon Linux?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/16244)

Answer (score 2):

Why doesn't Windows contain almost no GNU tools? How many people do you believe want to use highly specialized console applications for dealing with files and their contents on their smartphones? How easy is it to use console applications on devices most of which don't have a physical keyboard?

Speaking of the shell, Android does have it, it's just not exposed to the user by default as absolute most people will never want to touch it.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129044/discussion-on-answer-by-artem-s-tashkinov-why-all-versions-of-android-until-now).